# Capture DataFeedConnection errors using vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, odata

I have a data feed connection in excel. I'm trying to refresh a data feed connection using vbscript. Here's how I try to refresh the connection.

```
Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open('<excel file name/path>')
oWorkbook.Connections(1).Refresh
```

The total number of records returned by the data feed(OData) is actually huge and the conection isn't stable. Hence, I often get the error stating that "The connection is closed" while trying to refresh the connection from excel manually. A snapshot of the error below. Whenever I get this error, I try refreshing the connection again and this results in successful refresh most of the times.

[image]

I want to achieve the same result in vbscript as well. When I refresh the connection using vbscript, I get the same error and my script stops running as its unable to capture and handle the error.

In the documentaion I see that I can capture errors only if its [OLEDBError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/oledberrors-object-excel) or [ODBCError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/odbcerrors-object-excel). I'm not able to find the similar ways to capture DataFeedConnection error. Is there any way to capture the DataFeedConnection errors?

**Edit**: To update you with more information on the **vbscript**, the script picks up multiple files from the current folder, refresh the first or second connection depends on the file name and then compare certain values before and after refresh to make sure the refresh has happened successfully and then decide saving or closing the file based on the comparison results. The reason for comparison is there are some times refresh brings only partial data.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, adding an "On Error GoTo" then using a msgbox to display the error description:

```
Sub Foo()
On Error GoTo WhatHappened

    'Your code here

WhatHappened:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks your answer. Sorry, I had to roll back the edit you made to the question as the question is clearly about Visual Basic Script not Visual Basic for Application.